# Error after updating GoogleAppEngine app using Jersey

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey-2.0

I have a application I am porting to Google App Engine (GAE).  The code was working before, however now I am getting an error processing the HTTP request when I deploy to GAE ("java.lang.IllegalStateException").  The error in on injection and seems to be related something missing on the class path.

Here is the callstack:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected: (Errors.java:191)
MultiException stack 1 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent$HttpServletRequestReferencingFactory
    contracts={javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@46d91f62
    proxiable=true
    proxyForSameScope=false
    analysisName=null
    id=93
    locatorId=4
    identityHashCode=1486585668
    reified=true) requires a proxy, but the proxyable library is not on the classpath
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:1989)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ContextInjectionResolver.resolve(ContextInjectionResolver.java:126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:54)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:341)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:169)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:379)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.getProcessingProviders(ApplicationHandler.java:795)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:537)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:504)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.disneyinteractive.devon.module.AuthenticationFilterProvider errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:246)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:54)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:341)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:169)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:379)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.getProcessingProviders(ApplicationHandler.java:795)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:537)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:504)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.disneyinteractive.devon.module.AuthenticationFilterProvider
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:386)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:54)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:341)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:169)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:379)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllProviders(Providers.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.getProcessingProviders(ApplicationHandler.java:795)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:537)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:504)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I am reading that correctly I believe it's having trouble loading "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest".

**So the weird thing is that everything runs fine locally on the *DevAppServer*.**  I doubled checked, I did have one dependency that was set to *provided* in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Even if I change it to *compile* and re-deploy I still get the error.  It was my understanding that the servlet classes where in the SDK, which is why it's set to provided, and if you inspected the SDK under Maven Dependencies in Eclipse you can see the classes.

- appengine-api-1.0-sdk v1.9.42 (the latest in Maven Central)
- Jersey v2.23.2 (the latest in Maven Central)
- Jackson 2.5.4 (the version referenced by Jersey)
- Servlet API 2.5
- The GAE console says the instance is running App Engine Release 1.9.43.

An earlier version of the app was deployed and working fine, this occured when trying to push updates to GAE.  I am at a loss as I've been troubleshooting this for hours, so I thought maybe someone might have some ideas to help me figure out what is going on...

**EDIT:** I tried updating Jackson to the latest version, but that causes other issues in the Jersey code.

**EDIT:**
I think the issue is related to Injection. I have a very simply [now] Exception mapper class:

```
    package <redacted>;

    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException;
    import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

    @Provider
    public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenericExceptionMapper.class.getName());

        //@Context HttpHeaders headers;

        @Context
        ServletContext context;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper#toResponse(java.lang.Throwable)
         */
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

            return Response.serverError().status(msg.getStatus().getStatusCode()).entity(msg).build();
        }

}
```

This mapper works fine if I leave it as is, but if I uncomment the line:

> //@Context HttpHeaders headers;

It starts failing again.